# Local coordinates near point such that $X= \partial_1$ is relative to those coordinates, vector field with isolated s.t. coordinates do not exist?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-analysis, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a finite-dimensional smooth manifold, and let $X$ be a smooth vector field on $M$. Let $X(p) \neq 0$ for some $p \in M$.

- How do I show that I can find local coordinates near $p$ such that $X = \partial_1$ relative to these coordinates?
- What is an example of a vector field with an isolated zero for which such coordinates do not exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I show that I can find local coordinates near $p$ such that $X = \partial_1$ relative to these coordinates?

We may assume that $X$ is a vector field in $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $X(0) \neq 0$ where $p$ is $0$ in these local coordinates. Make a linear change of variables so that $X(0) = \partial_1$. The map$$(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) \mapsto \Phi_{x_1} (x_2, x_2, \dots, x_n)$$is a diffeomorphism near the origin; indeed, all we have to do is cite the Inverse Function Theorem, since the aforementioned map written down has the identity as its derivative at the point $0$.

> What is an example of a vector field with an isolated zero for which such coordinates do not exist?

An example of a vector field for which it is not possible to straighten is $x \partial_y - y \partial_x$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Indeed, in any neighborhood of $0$, we can not straighten the vector field even if we delete the point $0$ because the flow trajectories are circles.

Comment: This is also a good way to look at the existence of solutions of an ordinary differential equation: the local existence of integral curves of a vector field. If the vector field does not vanish near a point, then its flow can be linearised and one can easily integrate the equations for trajectories whose tangent vectors are given by the vector field. Now, when the vector field vanishes at a point: all the fun starts, and the trajectories near that point might be more interesting.